# How to pick values from a redirected_url using Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I want to be able to fetch a param from the redirect url whenever it is automated. I am having difficulties doing this as I am getting a bad request after I created another endpoint to effect this.

I have an endpoint that works fine. The endpoint is a get method. Loading the endpoint takes a user to a page where they need to provide some necessary details. Once these details have been verified, the user is redirected to my redirecr_uri. The redirect_uri now contains important information like session_id, code, etc. The  most important thing I need is the code. I need to pass the code into yet another endpoint which will return an access token.

I have manually done this process and it works but I want it to be done automatically because I can't keep doing that when I push the code to staging or production.

Here is the endpoint that redirects as well as the method.

```
@GetMapping("/get-token")
    public RedirectView getBvn() throws UnirestException {
        return nibss.getAccessToken();
    }
```

This is the method that the controller calls

```
public RedirectView getAccessToken() throws UnirestException {
        String url = "https://idsandbox.nibss-plc.com.ng/oxauth/authorize.htm?scope=profile&acr_values=otp&response" +
                "_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.accionmfb.com/&client_id=0915cd00-67f2-4768-99ac-1b2ff9f1da2e";

        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
        redirectView.setUrl(url);
        return redirectView;
    }
```

When the user provides the right information they are redirected to something like this

```
https://www.accionmfb.com/?code=9ad91f13-4698-4030-8a8f-a857e6a9907e&acr_values=otp&scope=profile&session_state=fa525cabc5b62854c73315d0322fd830c12a5941b89fd8e6e518da369e386572.b78a3d21-e98e-4e9a-8d60-afca779d9fad&sid=fd60ab92-ef37-4a5b-99b9-f8f52321985d
```

It is important to state that this 3rd party API I am trying to consume uses oath2.0 client authentication.

I created this endpoint to get the code from the redirected_uri

```
@GetMapping("/redirect-url")
    public void handleRedirect(@RequestParam("code") String code) throws UnirestException {
        if(Objects.nonNull(code) || !code.isEmpty()){
            nibss.getToken(code);
            log.info("Code is not being passed {}", code);

        } else {
            log.info("Code is not being passed {}", code);
        }

    }

public String getToken(String code) throws UnirestException {
        log.info("This is the code here oooooooooo {}", code);
        String url = "https://idsandbox.nibss-plc.com.ng/oxauth/restv1/token";

        String parameters = "client_id=0915cd00-67f2-4768-99ac-1b2ff9f1da2e&code="+code+"&redirect_uri=https://www.accionmfb.com/&grant_type=authorization_code";

        HttpResponse<String> apiResponse = Unirest.post(url)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic MDkxNWNkMDAtNjdmMi00NzY4LTk5YWMtMWIyZmY5ZjFkYTJlOlRVRnEwcGFBQXRzbzBZOEcxMkl2WFZHUmx6WG5zaERiaGt1dzI1YUM=")
                .body(parameters)
                .asString();
        //JSONObject apiJson = apiResponse.getBody().getObject();
        //return apiJson.getString("access_token");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(apiResponse.getBody());
        String accessToken = json.getString("access_token");
        log.info(accessToken);
        return accessToken;

    }
```

But this is not working, I get 400 whenever I hit the second endpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` that you are passing to the OAuth server is `https://www.accionmfb.com` which does not include the path `/redirect-url` so the redirect never hits your method.

Either register and pass a callback uri like `redirect_uri=https://www.accionmfb.com/redirect-url`

Or change `@GetMapping("/redirect-url")` to `@GetMapping("/")`

Comment: Be careful with `@GetMapping("/")`, it could effectively hijack the web site, if it answers all requests to the site root URL

Comment: I am still getting the same error. `"message": "Missing Request Parameter Exception",
    "error": [
        "code parameter is missing"
    ]`

Comment: This is progress - it looks like your redirect-url is being called (it requires the "code" parameter). In your question you show the callback as including code. Does it still? It seems you have done something to make the "code" vanish. The "response_type" parameter in the initial call to idsandbox.nibss-plc.com.ng?